# how do I print the stuct members using an array pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, struct

The code I have wrote so far is the following without the libraries. Basically I used the stdio.h and the stdlib.h.

```
typedef struct ID{
     char firstName[21];
     char lastName[21];
     char phoneNumber[11];
}ID;

ID PrintList(ID *ptr,int i){
     int l=1;
     printf(" #   First Name       Last Name       Phone Number\n");
     while(l<i+1)
     {
        printf(" %d.   %s",l,&ptr[l]);
        l++;
    }
} 

ID addNew(ID *ptr,int i){
    char fname[21],lname[21],phone[11];
    if(i<3)
     {  
        ID user;
        ptr[i] = user;
        printf("enter the first name:   ");
        scanf("%s",&fname);
        *ptr->firstName= fname;
        printf("enter the last name:    ");
        scanf("%s",&lname);
        *ptr->lastName = lname;
        printf("enter the phone number: "); 
        scanf("%s",&phone);
        *ptr->phoneNumber = phone;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("sorry but you have reach max capacity\n");  
    }
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int answere,i=0;
    printf("******* WELCOME TO PHONEBOOK **********\n\n\n");
    printf("***************************************\n");
    printf("*                MENU                 *\n");
    printf("*                                     *\n");
    printf("* 1.Add New   2.Print list     3.Exit *\n\n");
    printf("***************************************\n\n");

    ID* ptr=(int*)malloc(21*sizeof(ID));
    do
    {
        printf("Please select (1, 2 or 3): ");
        scanf("%d",&answere);
        if(answere!=1 && answere!=2 && answere!=3)
        {
            printf("...Error... \ngive me a correct answere\n");
        }
        if(answere == 1)
        {
            i++;
            addNew(ptr,i);
        }
        else if(answere==2)
        {
            PrintList(ptr,i);
        }
    }while(answere!=3); 

    return 0;
}
```

So as I said my problem is that I am not able to print the members of the struct as I need to print them using the array of pointers though. I think that I just haven't written something right like it is just a little logic mistake in `printf`. 
The only obstacle that I have is that the array of pointers is needed to be made in `main`.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", ptr[i].firstName);`

Comment: yes but not working

Comment: In which way "not working"? Crash? Hang? No output? Wrong output? Endless output? Compiler errors? Compiler warnings (you do use strict warnings don't you)? Segfault? Please describe what happens and in contrast to that  what you expected to happen? Do I guess right that you get each first name but want all struct members instead?

Comment: no output it just soing the first part of the messeng and when it comes the part of the variable its just goes on like its not there

Comment: also I have some compilers warning
in addnew and its showing 3 times 
[Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
in main
[Warning] initialization from incompatible pointer type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem completely lost...

### Some Basics

You are passing pointer/reference to first item of an array (address of the first item)
to get value at that address (dereference it) you can do two things:

- *ptr //but I don't recommend using it with structures
- ptr[0]

since you are using structures that are generally big you are expected to work with pointers and for that reason so called *"arrow"* operator exists which can be used to access members of structure pointer

- ptr->firstName

So your function would look like this:

```
    void PrintList(ID *ptr, int l)
    {
         int i;
         printf(" #   First Name       Last Name       Phone Number\n");
         for(i = 0; i < l; i++)
         {
            printf("%2d.   %s       %s       %s\n", 
i, ptr[i].firstName, ptr[i].firstName, ptr[i].phoneNumber);
        }
    }
```

Also I recommend using '\t' instead of spaces to align the columns.

Comment: well yeah I have a little prob, also yeah I am lost af but my problem is that it prints  #   First Name       Last Name       Phone Number
 0.   Ρh       MEDRIVE=C:       Users\user
 1.   LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local       \user\AppData\Local       OGONSERVER=\\USER-PC
 2.   \\USER-PC       ROCESSORS=4       C:\Users\user\OneDrive
 3.   er\OneDrive       s_NT       Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\user...

Comment: The easiest way would be this I think:
void addNew(ID* ptr, int id)
{
    while(getchar() != '\n'); //making sure that you start on a new line
    scanf("%s", ptr[id].firstName);
    while(getchar() != '\n');
    scanf("%s", ptr[id].lastName);
    while(getchar() != '\n');
    scanf("%s", ptr[id].phoneNumber);
}